# Power pivot CONCATENATEX function with filters

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

In PowerPivot I want to lookup all [Site] values for each row's following [Year], looking up the unique [ID] and a [Joined] tag which says "JOINED". A simple lookup! However, some rows have multiple [Site] values for the next [Year]. I want to produce the following [Destination] column:

```
[ID]    [Year]    [Site]    [Joined]    [Destination]
A       2012      London                London, LA
A       2013      London    JOINED
A       2013      LA        JOINED
B       2012      Paris                 Berlin, Madrid
B       2012      Paris                 Berlin, Madrid
B       2013      Berlin    JOINED
B       2013      Madrid    JOINED
```

The formula I have now is:

```
=concatenatex(
          filter(
                 Table,[Year]=([Year]+1)&&[ID]=earlier([ID])&&[Joined]="JOINED"),
                 Table[Site],
                 ",")
```

However this doesn't work. My formula may be wrong. Is there any way to do this? Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close. You need to put an `EARLIER` wrapper on the `Year` as well:

```
Destination = 
    CONCATENATEX(
        FILTER(Table,
               [Year] = EARLIER([Year]) + 1 &&
               [ID] = EARLIER([ID]) &&
               [Joined] = "JOINED"),
        Table[Site], ", ")
```